# How to restrict login attempts by users in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given an example of the objective in SQL (Oracle), that looks like:

```
DROP PROFILE restrictive  cascade;

CREATE PROFILE restrictive
    LIMIT FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 1
    PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 30
    PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME 7
    PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME 0;
```

But need to try and interpret this into SQL Server 2016. I'm new to the world of databases, and was hoping someone give me some pointers.

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy.

Answer (score 0):

*So this is what I came up with....*

```
ALTER LOGIN [jones] WITH CHECK_POLICY = ON;
ALTER LOGIN [jones] WITH CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON; 
GO 
SELECT USER jones FROM [sys].[sql_logins] 
WHERE [is_disabled] = 1; 

SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 7; 
GO
```